# moment-jalali validate on specific date

Tags: javascript, momentjs, angular-moment

```
var x = moment("13900229","YYYYMMDD",'fa').format("YYYY/MM/DD");
```

or

```
var x = moment("13900229").format("YYYY/MM/DD");
```

**output : Invalid Date**

but:

```
var x = moment("13900228","YYYYMMDD",'fa').format("YYYY/MM/DD");
```

or

```
var x = moment("13900228").format("YYYY/MM/DD");
```

**Output:1390/02/03**

Comment: Feb of 1390 wasn't a leap year it had 28 days only

Comment: No. Leap is effective in the last month of the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code :

```js
moment(date, 'jYYYYjMMjDD').format("jYYYY/jMM/jDD").toString();
```

the problem is solved